# Delivery different kind of protocols in a SOA architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, soap, soa

I have a project that is currently in production delivering some web-services using the REST approach. Right now, I need to delivery some of this web-services in SOAP too (it means that I will need to deliver some of the same web-services in SOAP and others a bit different), so, I ask you:

1. Should I incorporate to the existent project the SOAP stack (libraries, configuration files, ...), building another layer that deliver the data in envelopes way (some people call it "anti-corruption layer") ?
2. Should I build another project using just the canonical model in common (become it in a shared-library) ?
3. ... Or how do you proceed in similar situations ?

Please, consider our ideal target a SOA architecture.

Thanks.

Comment: Robson, can you describe a little of what your current REST services do?

Comment: @EricFarr, it´s all about business services (billing, CRM, HR, ...),  become some of that services to a SOAP model is needed because our CRM solution don´t know how to comunicate with REST services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our projects we have a facade layer which exposes the services and maps to business entities, and a business layer where the business logic is run.

So to add a SOAP end point for an existing service, we just create a new facade and call in to the same business logic.

In many cases it is even simpler, since we use WCF we can have a http SOAP endpoint for external clients, and a binary tcpip endpoint for internal clients. The new endpoint can be added by changing the configuration without any need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about an SOA system, you have messages and pub/sub. The message is the interface. Getting those messages into and out of the system is an implementation detail. I create an endpoint that accepts a raw message document (more REST-like, but not really REST) as well as an endpoint that accepts the message as a single parameter to a SOAP call. The code that processes the incoming message is a separate concern from the HTTP endpoint enablement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ESB for this. Where ESB receive the soap messages and send the rest request to the back end. WSO2 ESB provides this functionality. Please look at this sample[1].

[1] http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html#Sample152

Comment: This link is broken. Can you verify, please? 404 here.